Floor Joist Repair
I was doing a bathroom remodel recently and found that someone long before me had cut 90% out of a floor joist for a shower flange…I’m guessing 10-15 years ago, based on the shower I removed. The remodel included the removal of the shower and I’d hate to just leave this. There will be a double vanity and 2x8 quartz countertop installed above this, so I feel like it needs addressed prior to install. Important to note that there are a pair of steel I-beams 10ft away from this, running perpendicular to the joist, spanning the entire length of the house. These are supporting the floor joists. Would scabbing a 2x10x8 be a sufficient fix? Looking for input/recommendations.


it might need jacking up first, but sistering another board to it should be fine.

That cutout did appear to mess up the ducting intended in the adjacent joist bay.

nice how to video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deapHPV8QFc&t=476s
